# Select top 5 biggest values - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, selection

This is an Oracle question.

I need to find the top 5 biggest values in a series of records. Say I have 2000 records, and there is a column that holds number values in each record. I need to check this number field and only select the top 5 biggest.

So if I have these values in my number column

```
22
3
44
2
23
9
4
2
99
```

Then the following would be returned

```
22
44
23
9
99
```

I'm currently having to parse the number value from the field as it is a string. I parse it with the following

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(ADDITIONAL_INFO, 1 ,
              INSTR(ADDITIONAL_INFO, ',', 1,1)), '[0-9]+') "CELLS"
```

I'm thinking there might be looping and if else selection involved. If this were C# I could do this in a few minutes. But the Oracle syntax is throwing me off.

Please help.

Comment: If your column (as I think) contains the number you need and something else, please edit your question and show us some row please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ADDITIONAL_INFO FROM your_table
     ORDER BY to_number(ADDITIONAL_INFO) DESC) r
WHERE rownum <= 5
```

Comment: It won't work (`WHERE` must be before `ORDER BY`). It should be But `SELECT * FROM (your_query without where)a WHERE rownum<6`

Comment: @a1ex07: yes, you're right. I wrote my query too quick without notice my fault. I've just edited my answer. Thanks a lot! :)